# Unable to delete 'index.php' in wordpress's permalink on GAE

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, multisite

I'm trying to setup wordpress multisite on GAE.
Almost done, but I can not delete `index.php` in permalink url of each sites.

How can I delete `index.php` in wordpress site's url on GAE?

I use 'Custom Structure' and set `/%postname%/`, but RESET API's error occurs and the post can not be updated due to the error, `The response is not a valid JSON response.`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRDfe.jpg)

If `.htaccess` is valid, I can solve this problem, but GAE can not use `.htaccess` and use `app.yaml` instead.
I read documents about app.yaml (PHP7), but could not solve it.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you installed wordpress using this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-wordpress-on-appengine-standard).
Please read through the following for your understanding :

- [Google App Engine - PHP - app.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref)
- [Google App Engine - PHP - Simulate Apache mod_rewrite routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/mod_rewrite)

Steps for you to follow :

Step 1 :

- Run the following command to open your Apache2.conf file:

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

- Use the down-arrow key to scroll toward the bottom of the file, and
  locate this block of code:

> <Directory /var/www/> 
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
> AllowOverride None  
> Require all granted

On the line that says:

> **AllowOverride None**

Change it to:

> **AllowOverride All**

- Save and exit the file (CTRL + X, then Y, then ENTER), then restart
  your Apache server using :

> sudo service apache2 restart

Step 2:

- Change permalink settings in wp-admin to pretty permalinks
- Install mod_rewrite module in apache using :

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

- Restart apache using

> sudo service apache2 restart

For more details check this [link](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I'll try steps. (The GAE links is written not for PHP 7 but for PHP 5.)

Comment: Yes, you can click on "7" of PHP 5/7 option in the link provided. That will route you to the same documentation but with PHP 7 Runtime. Also let me know if these steps worked for you. Thanks!